# onclick Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android development. I recently encoutered an issue when I hit a button on my application. I'm not sure what caused this because it worked flawlessly before I did some editing with the app, adding another activity, removing the software menu buttons on the splash screen, some other stuff. Not much of it had to do with the first activity which is where this problem exists. I would've posted all of the code but this website refused to let me do so

When I hit my button (readybutton) I get the following error:

```
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        ComponentInfo 
  {com.unviewedchat/com.unviewedchat.SecondActivity}:
  java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.unviewedchat.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:23)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Button code (readybutton)

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.readybutton);
button1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
Button button1;

private void readyButtonclick()
{
 startActivity(new Intent("unviewedchat.SecondActivity"));
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.readybutton:
            readyButtonclick();
            break;

    }

}
```

**SecondActivity row 22-23**

```
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.help);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this); }
```

this code is for the software menu buttons to open the help screen, does this actually effect the button code for FirstActivity?

There is no code on SecondActivity that i'm trying to access, i'm trying to go to that activity when someone hits the button.

I attempted to post all of the error report, only to get told it wasn't formatted correctly when it was, either way I added almost all of it.

Comment: some object you are trying to  access in your SecondActivity, is null

Comment: You should post some relevant code from your application so we can help you out better.

Comment: post the code of the both the activites

Comment: "I would've posted all of the code" -> Please don't. But posting the relevant parts (code of the first activity, for example) could be interesting if you want us to help you further. Welcome to StackOverflow, BTW ;-)

Comment: Try this : startActivity(new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class)); and please define this activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Post the full stacktrace, including the "caused by" part that actually tells the line of code where the NPE is.

Comment: this is your declaration for your project package

    com.unviewedchat 

so even if you want to access it that way you should add the "com" to it.. but follow BatuhanC answer its the best way..

Comment: So the NPE is in your `SecondActivity.java` row 23 - please post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change:

```
startActivity(new Intent("unviewedchat.SecondActivity"));
```

with this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.unviewedchat.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:23)

So in here:

> SecondActivity row 22-23
>
> ```
> button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.help);
> button2.setOnClickListener(this); }
> ```

... `button2` is `null`. Either your layout you've set with `setContentView()` does not contain a view with id `help`, or you haven't called `setContentView()` at all. In either case `findViewById()` returns `null`.

Comment: It depends how the menu is implemented. Anyway, at the time you're calling `findViewById()` the `help` button is not in the activity view hierarchy.

Comment: Edit the question and add where the `help` button is exactly and how you're incorporating it to `SecondActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

where in the SecondActivity do you declare button2?
you should do it in the onCreate method **after** setContentView()
and check your layout you are in SecondActivity if the button with that specific id "help" actually exists

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

use the code following code

```
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.menu.help);
```

instead of

```
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.help);
```